# Memory View Causes Segfault Eclipse C/C++

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

I'm having a really annoying issue with Eclipse C/C++. I'm trying to test out the built in memory viewer included with the debugger, but when I try to view the value at an address my program crashes.

For my example, I just made a basic integer x and a pointer to it, y.

[image]

As you can see, I then took the address of x and tried to view it in the memory viewer. As soon as But as soon as I hit OK, my program terminated.

[image]

-1073741819 exit code on my system is a Segfault. Anyone have an idea what's causing this?